# How do I use conditionally formatting on a date which depends on another cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using conditional formatting on a column of dates, so they turn red if today's date is after what date in the cell.

But, I would like it to only turn red if the cell next to it matches a certain word.

Example:

A1 = 1-jan-2019 and B1 = SELECT

I would like A1 to turn red, but only if B1 has SELECT in it.

Google Sheets has a nice function to handle to date, but if it has to depend on a different cell, I have to choose custom, and come up the code myself - which I don't know :-)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the following custom formula :
`=AND($A:$A<TODAY(),$B:$B="SELECT")`

Also attaching a screenshot:
[image: Conditional formatting based on custom formula on 2 cells]

Answer (score 0):

In your `conditional formatting` choose *Custom Formula* as follow:

```
=AND($A:$A<TODAY(),REGEXMATCH($B:$B, "SELECT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=(A1<TODAY())*(B1="select")
```

[image]